# Using read and write system calls with sprintf

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I'm to use only read and write system calls for a c program. Therefore, can't use anything like printf, getc, etc etc. Since I can't use printf, I need to use sprintf for this. However, I can't find examples for how to use sprintf with file i/o system calls. I need o use write(....), read(.....)

Comment: `char buffer[100]; sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", some_int); write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));`

Answer (score 1):

File-I/O through system calls is simpler and operates at a lower level than making calls to the C file-I/O library. 
Use of these system calls requires a header file named "fcntl.h":

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
```

The `"creat()`" system call, of course, creates a file. It has the syntax:

```
<file descriptor variable> = creat( <filename>, <protection bits> );

ex:

   #define RD_WR 0666 
   int fd;                               /Define file descriptor. */    
   fd = creat( "data", RD_WR );
```

The `"open()"` system call opens an existing file for reading or writing. It has the syntax

```
   <file descriptor variable> = open( <filename>, <access mode> );

   O_RDONLY    Open for reading only.
   O_WRONLY    Open for writing only.
   O_RDWR      Open for reading and writing.
ex:
   int fd;
   fd = open( "data", O_WRONLY );
```

The `"close()"` system call is very simple. All it does is `"close()"` an open file when there is no further need to access it. The `"close()"` system call has the syntax:

```
   close( <file descriptor> );
```

The `"write()"` system call writes data to an open file. It has the syntax:

```
   write( <file descriptor>, <buffer>, <buffer length> );
ex:
  float array[10];
   ...
   write( fd, array, sizeof( array ) );
```

The `"read()"` system call reads data from a open file. Its syntax is exactly the same as that of the `"write()"` call:

```
   read( <file descriptor>, <buffer>, <buffer length> );
```

Comment: What about my sprintf question?

Comment: so you want `sprintf` for file i/o? `sprintf` use for write to/read from strings not file. For file use `fprintf`.